# Where's XMLImporter utility on Oracle EBS 12.2.3?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

I have a new installation of Oracle EBS 12.2.3 (the single node VM template downloaded from Oracle setup with the Vision db) but I am having difficulties locating the oracle.jrad.tools.xml.importer.XMLImporter utility that used to be included in earlier versions; supposedly, it's just a class file under $JAVA_TOP but executing `find . -iname "XMLImporter.class"` under the `/u01/install/VISION` directory do not yield any results.  What is the location of this utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - it's in oamdsdt.zip under COMMON_TOP/java/lib